# how do hidden markov models recognize a word?

Tags: speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models

I just read this post here (the first answer):

https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-hidden-Markov-Model-HMM-and-how-can-it-be-used-in-speech-recognition

I kinda get it, but not fully. Without getting too technical: How exactly does the word recognition work?

In the post, the hmm should recognize the word "cat" represented by the phonemes `/k/ /a/ /t/`.

So let's say the hmm is in the state for /k/. That means, it successfully recognized the /k/, right?

How exactly does it then recognize the /a/? There is a certain probability that after /k/ the next state is /a/, but also, e. g. that the next state is /e/, right?

Do these probabilities come from training the model on the corpus? So, if most words in the corpus are /ka/ instead of /ke/, the probability to go from state /k/ to /a/ is higher than to go from state /k/ to /e/?

In what way is it determined  that next it will go to the state for /a/ and not to /e/?

And it says that the phonemes are the hidden parts... Does that mean, we cant see, which phoneme the model chose, we can just see that now it is in the state for /k/? And we can only see, which phonemes it chose, after it processed the entire word and the outcome is either correct or not?

And that would mean that it can only ever go from /k/ to /a/ but you cannot guarantee that it finds the correct phonemes...?

I'm not trying to understand the ins and outs of this model, just generally how it works for speech recognition.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to read more reputable sources than random Quora answers to get full idea about complex algorithms. For example, Rabiner's HMM tutorial is a good idea. You can also check a textbook like [Spoken Language Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130226165) which gives a good description for the subject.

The sequence of observable events in speech recognition is sequence of audio frames. Each frame is roughly 20ms of sound. The sequence of unobservable events is roughly the sequence of phonemes. Actually it is more complex, but you can think phonemes. Beside HMM model which is just mathematical object, there is an important part about decoding algorithm called Viterbi search which finds the best match between observable and hidden states according to the probabilities. This algorithm efficiently evaluates all possible breakdowns and find the best one. That best one would be the decoding result.

> So let's say the hmm is in the state for /k/. That means, it successfully recognized the /k/, right?

There is no such thing as "hmm in state k". We consider frame 1 and say it corresponds to "k", then we consider frame 2 and decide does it correspond to "k", to "a" or to "e". For that we use previous state for previous frame and also acoustic match between the frame 2 and all three states. This acoustic match is usually estimated with separate model, for example gaussian mixture model, do not confuse it with hidden markov model. Both models are estimated from the corpus. After we store some possible decisions for frame 2 we move to frame 3 to decide does it belong to any of expected hidden states. Notice we do not keep 1 best decision but multiple possible decisions on the way because locally best decision (2 corresponds to a) might not be globally best (2 corresponds to e). In the end of decoding we have a full relation between hidden and observable states and we can estimate the probability of this relation using HMM.

> How exactly does it then recognize the /a/? There is a certain probability that after /k/ the next state is /a/, but also, e. g. that the next state is /e/, right?

It compares probabilities of breakdowns combined with the GMM score for this frame to update probabilities of breakdowns including this new frame.
GMM score tells how good is match of the audio to the expected sound of "a" and is trained from the database.

> And it says that the phonemes are the hidden parts... Does that mean, we cant see, which phoneme the model chose, we can just see that now it is in the state for /k/? And we can only see, which phonemes it chose, after it processed the entire word and the outcome is either correct or not?

We can only see phonemes after processing the entire word.

> And that would mean that it can only ever go from /k/ to /a/ but you cannot guarantee that it finds the correct phonemes...?

Locally you can not guarantee that, you need to compare global picture or at least to do some iterations after current phoneme. Thats why you have to keep multiple decoding results during search, not just the best single one.